# Sharing object amongst users in single-table DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am relatively new to the single-table design and I am creating a single-table database that incorporates sharing amongst members and **I want to be able to send one query that returns all objects and object details associated with a user**.

Here is a toy example of what I mean:

Let's say there is a single-table with car details while relating car details with owners. The PK car contains car, engine, owner, title, and wheels info. Here is the table:

[image]

The access pattern I am trying to model is returning all of the cars **AND CAR DETAILS** for a user, in this case user#9128. With a global secondary index of the inverse of PK/SK (GSI-1PK = SK, GSI-1SK = PK) I can get the user information and the cars associated with them (2), but I obviously don't get the car details such as the engine, wheels, and title details. I can send follow-up queries for each car but that seems costly, so ideally I would get the data in one call.

[image]

**Is there another way I can structure the data so that I can get all of the car details associated with a user while maintaining the ability to add multiple users to the car?**

Thanks!

Comment: You can project all the attributes to the index when you create it: `Projection: {"ProjectionType": "ALL"},`.

Answer (score 0):

You either issue the second request (which isn’t that costly, it’s what a relational database would do internally when issuing a join like this) or you denormalize the data to keep a copy of the car data stored under a user record and maintain the data sync yourself, then you can do a quick fetch. Which is best depends on your latency needs.